Every Compact Set in the Complement of the Support of a Regular Finite Positive Measure Is of Measure Zero.
Suppose $(\Omega, d)$ is a metric space, let $\mathfrak{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $(\Omega, d)$, and let $\mu:\mathfrak{B}\to[0, \infty)$ be a finite positive measure. Then the support of $\mu$ is defined as follows:
$$supp(\mu) := \{a\in \Omega \mid \forall r>0: \mu(B(a;r)) > 0  \}$$
I want to prove that if one supposes that $\mu$ is regular, then $U:=\text{[}\Omega \setminus supp(\mu)\text{]}$ has $\mu(U)=0$.
The definition of regularity as I know it is:
$\mu$ is regular if for every $B \in \mathfrak{B}$ and $\epsilon > 0$:
$$\exists F, G \subseteq \Omega:(\text{[F is compact]}, \text{[G is open]}, \text{[}F\subseteq B \subseteq G \text{]}, \text{[}\mu(G) - \mu(F) < \epsilon\text{]})$$
In trying to do the proof, I have already proven that $\mu(G) = \mu(U)$ for the open $G \supseteq U$ in the definition of regularity.
If I could prove that for every compact $K \subseteq U(=\text{[} \Omega \setminus supp(\mu) \text{]})$, $\mu(K)=0$, the proof would be complete, but so far I have not been able to show it. Can anyone guide me?

By the way, one can actually show that $U$ is open, since if $a \in U$ then there is $r>0$ with $\mu(B(a;r)) = 0$, and then you can show $B(a;r) \subseteq U$. So you only need $\mu$ to be inner regular.

@arkeet Yeah I have already shown that it's open. I guess my problem was in using compactness to my advantage. Thanks for your response.

If $a \in K$ then $a \notin \operatorname{supp}(\mu)$, so we can choose $r(a) > 0$ such that $\mu(B(a;r(a))) = 0$. The sets $\{ B(a; r(a)) \mid a \in K \}$ are an open cover of $K$, and since $K$ is compact there is a finite collection of $a_i$ such that
$$K \subseteq \bigcup_i B(a_i; r(a_i)).$$
The right side is a finite union of sets of measure zero, so $\mu(K) = 0$.
